# How to Capture multiple screen screenshot in flutter desktop?

Tags: flutter, dart, screenshot, flutter-desktop, find-package

I am looking for a way or package that can help me to capture multiple screen.

I have been through some packages that supports single fullscreen screenshot but I want to capture all the screens connected.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Flutter does not provide an API for capturing screenshots of multiple screens that are connected to the same device. To capture screenshots of multiple screens, you would need to use an operating system-level tool or an external screen capture software.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you cant do it in flutter you have to write native code to the platform you target, because flutter only can give access to app level not system level